# Python AST code sample taken from the book Serious Python: Black-Belt Advice on Deployment, Scalability, Testing, and More

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm reading the book Serious Python: Black-Belt Advice on Deployment, Scalability, Testing, and More from Julien Danjou and I'm having trouble from a code got from chapter 8.
This is the code:

```
import ast
hello_world = ast.Str(s = 'hello world!', lineno=1, col_offset=1)
print_name = ast.Name(id='print', ctx=ast.Load(), lineno=1, col_offset=1)
print_call =  ast.Call(func=print_name, ctx=ast.Load(), args=[hello_world], keywords=[], lineno=1, col_offset=1)
module = ast.Module(body=[ast.Expr(print_call, lineno=1, col_offset=1)], lineno=1, col_offset=1)
code = compile(module, '', 'exec')
eval(code)
```

And It's giving for me the follow error:

```
code = compile(module, '', 'exec')
TypeError: required field "type_ignores" missing from Module
```

I double check if I was typing something wrong but I didn't find anything wrong.

Can someone give me a clue, please?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error and how to fix it is explained [in this issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/11590): There were changes in the python ast module, probably after the book came out, `ast.Module` now expects you to pass a list called `type_ignores`. For your purposes, you can just pass an empty list:

```py
module = ast.Module(
    body=[ast.Expr(print_call, lineno=1, col_offset=1)],
    lineno=1,
    col_offset=1,
    type_ignores=[],
)
```

[full working code example here](https://www.online-python.com/f1euW978Bm).